# Using an image as a button that calls a function on-click Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a game of rock paper scissors. When I click on my input, the function is not invoked. I am wondering if I am overlooking anything in my code:

```
function LFG(){
    var c=math.random();
    if (c<0.3333){
        cmove="r";
        document.getElementById("playahater").src("rightRockHand.jpg");
    }
    if (c>0.3333 && c<0.6666){
        cmove="p";
        document.getElementById("playahater").src("rightHandPaper.jpg");
    }
    if (c>0.6666){
        cmove="s";
        document.getElementById("playahater").src("rightHandScissors.jpg");
    }
    return cmove;
}

function rock(){
    LFG();
    document.getElementById("playa").src("leftRockHand.jpg");
    if (cmove == "r"){
        ties += ties;
        return ties;
    }
    if (cmove == "p"){
        losses += losses;
        return losses;
    }
    if (cmove == "s"){
        wins += wins;
        return wins;
    }
}
```

This code covers all of my functions, switching the second function for the logical substitute for paper and scissors. Here is where the function is invoked

```
<td><input onclick="scissor()" type="image" src="scissors.jpg" alt="scissors" id="scissors"/></td>
```

Comment: from the code you posted, you are trying to call a function called `scissor`, but you haven't made any function with that name, just `LFG` and `rock`. Also, you have an if statement what is comparing `cmove` in your 'rock' function, but you are never setting `cmove`, on the first line of rock do `var cmove = LFG()`

Comment: Also the return value of `LFG()` is missing in the rock function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Joe! I have a function called 'scissor()', it is essentially the same as 'rock()' but with different if statements and a different innerhtml

Comment: `var cmove = LFG();` you're not catching the return value of `LFG()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rock(){
var cmove = LFG(); <-- here is your fix 
document.getElementById("playa").src("leftRockHand.jpg");
if (cmove == "r"){
    ties += ties;
    return ties;
}
if (cmove == "p"){
    losses += losses;
    return losses;
}
if (cmove == "s"){
    wins += wins;
    return wins;
}
}
```